# Middle mouse clicks are ignored because of Task Switcher

Tags: windows-10, mouse, mouse-click, mouse-wheel

I'm currently using two different Windows 10 PCs:

The first uses Win 10 20H2 and a wired Logitech M500 mouse (=old model). The second uses Win 10 21H2 and a wired Logitech M500S mouse (=new model).

Pressing and holding the mouse wheel on the first PC in e.g. the browser does the usual "fast scroll". Doing the same thing on the second PC activates the Task Switcher (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>), which overrides the scrolling function and also causes problems in applications like Blender (which uses the middle mouse button to rotate the view, which isn't possible now).

If I connect the M500S model to the first PC, "fast scroll" works as intended, also no problems if I connect the regular M500 to the second PC. Neither PC has any extra driver software installed and, according to the device manager, both PCs use the same mouse driver.

I already uninstalled the S model on the second PC through device manager and after a restart "fast scroll" works for about a minute but then the middle mouse button goes back to opening the Task Switcher - the driver version doesn't change though. I also tried to uninstall the S model, then plug in the M500 model instead and have Windows install its drivers but as soon as I plug in the S model, the problem is back (after about a minute).

I'm aware I could switch mice for now but I'd rather fix this problem because it might appear on the first PC too once I update it. I also don't want to install any extra third-party software to change keybinds, as this is a problem caused by Windows and I'd rather also solve it through Windows' settings.

How do I disable the Task Switcher function for middle mouse click on the second PC (with the M500S) / how do I change it back to regular "fast scroll" in e.g. browsers and to whatever functions other applications use it for?

Comment: Does your mouse support action-mapping settings in *Control Panel > Mouse* like [this](https://superuser.com/a/390797/8672)?

Comment: @harrymc Sorry about the delayed reply! I checked the control panel but it opens the same dialog I get through `Settings > Devices > Mouse > Additional mouse options` (like [this](http://i.imgur.com/5crgemG.png)).